# Why does my response.sendRedirect( returnURL ) end up killing any domain cookies I've set?

Tags: jsp, cookies, response.redirect

Basically...anytime a user logs into my site, I create a cookie with encrypted Customer data.  No problems doing that.

However, if a 3rd-party-site user clicks our Login link, I need to not only create this same encrypted Customer cookie but also redirect them to a 'returnURL' that I build from their 3rd-party-site-generated URL.

No problem doing that either. The 'returnURL' gets the proper mapping, etc.   However, when I make the call to "response.sendRedirect(returnURL)", I get redirected to the 3rd-party site of the same domain as the cookie (which is correct)...but ALL COOKIES ARE NOW GONE.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have some ideas but it isn't 100% clear from your question what is going on. Could you expand your question with a sequence of events including some sample URLs, when cookies are created, when they are sent and when they are missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I answered as if OP asked about ASP.NET, while he actually talked about JSP.** I'll leave my answer here for reference, but it irrelevant to the question.

If you do a `Response.Redirect();` which results in `Response.End();` being called (either passing true as the 2nd paramter, or not passing a 2nd parameter at all), you will lose session data if it's the first time you write session information for the user. For example, after a login, you might set do:

```
Session["userId"] = userId;
Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
```

The solution is to call

```
Response.Redirect("admin.aspx", false);
```

You will only lose session data if the session does not yet exist when you do the redirect. What doesn't get set here is not the session data in itself, it's the cookie that identifies the session.

Betrand LeRoy explains this in greater detail:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/207486.aspx